# Trying to use ng-csv with data from FireBase in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, csv, firebase

I am trying to use ng-csv to allow a user to download a .csv file by clicking a button. The information is stored in Firebase and I have created a function that returns the needed information from Firebase as an array. However, I think the problem is when the button is clicked the file is downloaded before the information is pulled from Firebase and loaded, so the .csv file is always empty. Is there a way around this? Here is my code in my main.js app:

```
this.export = function() {
  var results = fireFactory.getResults() //code that returns the array of objects
  results.$loaded().then(function(array) {
    var test= [];
    test.push(array[0]);
    test.push(array[1]);
    return test;
  };
};
```

Here is my code in my HTML file:

```
<button class ="btn" ng-csv="main.export()" filename="test.csv">Export</button>
```

Is there anyway to delay the file downloading until the information has been loaded and returned from the main.export() function?

Comment: Please don't repost your previous question. If you have more information to add to your original question, use the "edit" link that is under that question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to get ng-csv to work with Firebase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331595/trying-to-get-ng-csv-to-work-with-firebase)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this implementation of promises/deferred objects in angularjs Doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue before, I solved it by fill the returned value using promise request. Try to make the export function as the following:

```
this.export = function() {
  var results = fireFactory.getResults(); //code that returns the array of objects
  var csvData = results.$loaded().then(function(array) {
     var test= [];
     test.push(array[0]);
     test.push(array[1]);
     return test;
  };
  return csvData;
};
```

The export function should return the array which is come from the request. And also you should add `lazy-load` in the HTML element as the following:

```
<button class ="btn" ng-csv="main.export()" filename="test.csv" lazy-load="true">Export</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$scope.ExportCsv = async function() {
    const msg = await getdata();
    return msg;
}
var getdata = function abc(a, b) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
                    $http.get( // use backend)
                        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                            $scope.datacsv = [];
                            angular.forEach($scope.dt, function(value, key) {
                                $scope.datacsv.push({
                                    "a":value.a,
                                    "b":value.b});
                                });
                            })
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                resolve($scope.datacsv);
                            }, 2000);
                        });
                    }
```

```html
<button type="button" ng-csv="ExportCsv()" filename="ExportCsv.csv" csv-header="['a','b']" charset="utf-8">CSV</button>
```